# Datalist for results in database

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-datalist

I've got this link [which shows how to predefine possible answers for easier search](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp). I am curious, is there possibility to make a... form, that loads data from all rows in specific column and set is as datalist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example PHP function to create a datalist 4.

```
<?php
    function datalist($name, $values) {
        if((is_string($name)&&(strlen($name)>0)) && (is_array($values))) {
            echo "<datalist id=\"{$name}\">";
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                echo "<option value=\"{$value}\"/>";
            }
            echo "</datalist>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<p class=\"error\">ERROR: Failed to create datalist.</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Answers seems valid. You get upvote, and I'll mark it as helpful answer as soon, as I test it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at th [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. You can get all the row values in one. If you define proper separator you can get the list